# Reset xamarin.forms.shell to initial page on back button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Very short version is
I want to, in code,  make the shell go to where it was, and how it looked, when it first displayed on app start.

I have a xamarin.forms.shell page which shows a number of content pages using flyout and tabs.
When the shell initially loads, it shows the first flyout item content page, which is my "main activity/page" with the most common UI.

If I go to another flyout item content page, I would like the backbutton to navigate to the "main flyout" and only if back button is clicked on this "main flyout", should it leave the app.

While I can intercept the backbutton and navigate to other pages, it does not have the effect of clicking the "main page" flyout. If I do

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync(name of route to my main flyout);
```

I do get to that main page, but as fullscreen and the flyout menu, toolbar and tabs are gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to override the [Back button behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#back-button-behavior), in your desired content page by defining a command that will be fired when the user pressed the back button in that page and then navigate to your root page by it defined root:

**CatsPage.Xaml**

```
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
   <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding BackCommand}"/>
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

**Code-Behind or ViewModel**

```
public ICommand BackCommand { get; private set; }

public CatsPage()  //or VM constructor
{
    ...
BackCommand = new Command(async (x) => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///MainRoute"));
}
```

If you are using this content page as a `Tab` content in more than one `FlyoutItem`, but you only want this behavior to work on the the `ContentPage` residing in the first `FlyoutItem` you may add a conditional test based on page absolute route or `Title` property:

Xaml example from jiang answer:

```
<FlyoutItem Route="MainRoute"
            Title="Animals"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <Tab Title="MainPage"
         Route="MainPage"
         Icon="paw.png">
        <ShellContent Route="cats"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      Title="Cats"
                      Icon="cat.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      Title="Dogs"
                      Icon="dog.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
    </Tab>

    <ShellContent Route="PageTwo"
                  Style="{StaticResource MonkeysShell}"
                  Title="Monkeys"
                  Icon="monkey.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />

    <ShellContent Route="cats"
                  Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                  Title="Cats2"
                  Icon="cat.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

**Code-Behind or ViewModel**

```
public CatsPage() //or VM constructor
{
    ...
    BackCommand = new Command(async (x) => {
    if (Shell.Current.CurrentState.Location.ToString().Equals("//MainRoute/MainPage/Cats"))
      //popup to quit
else if (Shell.Current.CurrentState.Location.ToString().Equals("//MainRoute/Cats"))
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///MainRoute");
    // or use to go back to previous: await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
   });
}
```

**Once again you need to properly define and use your `Tab`s and `FlyoutItem` routes hierarchy otherwise it will result in an exception**.

Comment: You both (you and Junior Jiang) gave me the clue I needed, which was to not jump to a route pointing to the specific page by class, but to a route pointing to the flyoutitem. Obvious, now I think about it, but that was where I went wrong. 
I would have liked to mark both as answer, but having to pick, I chose this one before it also shows Shell.Current.CurrentState.Location which is a simple solution to seeing what behavior back should invoke.

Answer (score 1):

> If I go to another flyout item content page, I would like the backbutton to navigate to the "main flyout" and only if back button is clicked on this "main flyout", should it leave the app.

You could store a page flag type when each page shows to determine whether it's the main page. And the page flag type only need to define two type: **One** is `0`(means main page), **another** is `1`(other pages). Then when pressing physical back button, you can determine whether need to show the exit message to exit the app.

For example, using **[Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android)** to store flag in `OnAppearing` method of each page:

MainPage:

```
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Preferences.Set("PageType", "0");
    }
}
```

OtherPage:

```
public partial class OtherPage : ContentPage
{
    public OtherPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Preferences.Set("PageType", "1");
    }
}
```

Then when back button be clicked, we can determine what we need to do.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pageType = Preferences.Get("PageType", "0");
    if (pageType == "0")
    {
        // Exit application method
        ExitApplication();
    }
    else
    {
        // back to the Main Page
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//MainRoute/MainPage");
    }
}
```

Here is the `Xaml` code of **FlyoutItem** :

```
<FlyoutItem Route="MainRoute"
            Title="Animals"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <Tab Title="MainPage"
         Route="MainPage"
         Icon="paw.png">
        <ShellContent Route="cats"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      Title="Cats"
                      Icon="cat.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      Title="Dogs"
                      Icon="dog.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
    </Tab>

    <ShellContent Route="PageTwo"
                  Style="{StaticResource MonkeysShell}"
                  Title="Monkeys"
                  Icon="monkey.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="PageThree"
                  Style="{StaticResource ElephantsShell}"
                  Title="Elephants"
                  Icon="elephant.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ElephantsPage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="PageFour"
                  Style="{StaticResource BearsShell}"
                  Title="Bears"
                  Icon="bear.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:BearsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Is `Button_Clicked()` an event handler of a user custom button defined in it page ?

Comment: @Cfun Here is, but you also can define it in native platform to invoke the physical back button.