# Xamarin application not navigating back

Tags: xamarin.forms

**Problem**

This is the process:

1. Select a `category` from list.
2. Load `Tasks page`.
3. `Tasks` are loaded depending on the `categoryId` selected from the previous page. *(Navigate back to `Category page` is possible ✔️)*
4. Select a `Task` from from list.
5. Load `Task Page`.
6. Task details are loaded on the page. *(Navigate back to Tasks page is not possible ❌)*

**Video**

[image]

**Question**

I do not understand why I cannot navigate back a page. How can I fix this?

**Code**

**CategoriesViewModel**

```
public class CategoriesViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> Categories { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CategoryModel>();

    public Command LoadCategoriesCommand { get; }
    public Command<CategoryModel> SelectedCategory { get; }

    public CategoriesViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Categories";

        LoadCategoriesCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadCategories());
        SelectedCategory = new Command<CategoryModel>(OnSelectedCategory);
    }

    private async Task LoadCategories()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        try
        {
            Categories.Clear();

            var categories = await DatabaseService.GetCategoriesAsync();
            foreach (var category in categories)
            {
                this.Categories.Add(category);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    private async void OnSelectedCategory(CategoryModel category)
    {
        if (category == null)
            return;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(TasksPage)}?{nameof(TasksViewModel.CategoryId)}={category.CategoryId}");
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }
}
```

**TasksViewModel**

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(CategoryId), nameof(CategoryId))]
public class TasksViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TaskModel> Tasks { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TaskModel>();

    private int categoryId;
    public int CategoryId
    {
        get { return categoryId; }
        set
        {
            categoryId = value;
        }
    }

    public Command LoadTasksCommand { get; set; }
    public Command<TaskModel> SelectedTask { get; set; }

    public TasksViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Tasks";
        LoadTasksCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadTasks());
        SelectedTask = new Command<TaskModel>(OnSelectedTask);
    }

    private async Task LoadTasks()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        try
        {
            this.Tasks.Clear();

            var tasks = await DatabaseService.GetTasksAsync(CategoryId);
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                this.Tasks.Add(task);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    private async void OnSelectedTask(TaskModel task)
    {
        if (task == null)
            return;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(TaskPage)}?{nameof(TaskViewModel.TaskId)}={task.TaskId}");
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }
}
```

**TaskViewModel**

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(TaskId), nameof(TaskId))]
public class TaskViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private int taskId;

    public int TaskId
    {
        get { return taskId; }
        set
        {
            taskId = value;
        }
    }

    private string taskTitle;

    public string TaskTitle
    {
        get { return taskTitle; }
        set
        {
            taskTitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TaskTitle));
        }
    }

    private string description;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Description));
        }
    }

    public Command LoadTaskCommand { get; }

    public TaskViewModel()
    {
        LoadTaskCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadTask());
    }

    private async Task LoadTask()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        try
        {
            var task = await DatabaseService.GetTaskAsync(TaskId);
            this.TaskTitle = task.Title;
            this.Description = task.Description;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

I tried replacing this line of code in `TasksViewModel`:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(TaskPage)}?{nameof(TaskViewModel.TaskId)}={task.TaskId}");
```

to this:

```
await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new AboutPage());
```

Also, the same outcome.

**Update 2**

As per requested comment, here is the `TaskPage.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SomeProject.ViewModels"
             x:Class="SomeProject.Views.Task.TaskPage"
             Title="{Binding TaskTitle}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RefreshView x:DataType="vm:TaskViewModel"
                     Command="{Binding LoadTaskCommand}"
                     IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </RefreshView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and `TaskPage.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class TaskPage : ContentPage
{
    TaskViewModel _viewModel;
    public TaskPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new TaskViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _viewModel.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

**Update 3**

As per requested comment, here is the `routes`:

```
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(CategoriesView), typeof(CategoriesView));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TasksPage), typeof(TasksPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TaskPage), typeof(TaskPage));
}
```

Comment: What does the TaskPage look like? Any code behind?

Comment: Also, do you see any error messages in the output / log while opening or closing the TaskPage?

Comment: @alsed42 I'll update the question in a moment. Regarding your 2nd comment, no - not binding errors, or any other errors - all clean.

Comment: @alsed42 Updated - see `Update 2` :)

Comment: If you override Shell BackButtonBehavior, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64220843/199364), and put a breakpoint in that method, does it stop at that breakpoint? If so, looking at variables in debugger, does it show somewhere what page it is trying to go to?

Comment: Also, I don't see in your code the "hierarchy" or "routes" defined for your shell navigation.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I'll take a look at the answer you provided - also added routes in my question. See update 3

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I added code from the answer you provided from the link, I used `GoToAsync("..)` to go back a page. This was the exception when called: `System.ArgumentException: 'Ambiguous routes matched for: //D_FAULT_FlyoutItem4/IMPL_CategoryPage/CategoryPage/TasksPage matches found: //D_FAULT_FlyoutItem4/IMPL_CategoryPage/CategoryPage/TasksPage,//D_FAULT_FlyoutItem4/IMPL_CategoryPage/CategoryPage/TasksPage
Parameter name: uri'`

Comment: Ah - I think I got it... I had `CategoryPage` registered in `AppShell.xaml.cs` and also `AppShell.xaml` like so: `<ShellContent Route="CategoryPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CategoryPage}" />` I didn't know this actually registers a route :/

Comment: Shell navigation seems a bit tricky to me. Works fine in simple cases, but people keep getting tripped up by details like this. I personally don't use Shell, I just have pages (no Shell), push the one I want next, pop to get back. What's weird with shell, is that if there is route, it doesn't push it on to nav stack. so you can't pop, as you just discovered!

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve 6 hours later.. finally managed to solve it. This ones is a painful one :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `CategoryPage` registered in `AppShell.xaml.cs` and also `AppShell.xaml` like so:

```
<ShellContent Route="CategoryPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CategoryPage}" />
```

Only can register one route in one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Check your registers route.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-page-routes

> In the Shell subclass constructor, or any other location that runs
> before a route is invoked, additional routes can be explicitly
> registered for any pages that aren't represented in the Shell visual
> hierarchy